# Replace function with variable and use it in return value

Tags: mysql, sql

I have sql query, where if the difference between 2 times is greater than 1440, then it will divide by 7, if not it will return the actual value. The problem is that I am repeating the code in the return value.

```
SELECT
'IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, now(), end_at) > 1440, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, now(), end_at)/ 7, TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, now(), end_at)) as minutesLeft'
FROM table
```

How can I replace the repeating code to look like this?

```
SELECT
'IF(TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, now(), end_at) > 1440, timestamp / 7, timestamp ) as minutesLeft'
FROM table
```

Comment: Yea but I am thinking that if I execute the same code 3 times, mysql will calculate each time. But if I store the value from the first time, second and third will not be calculated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using in-statement assignments:

```
set @diff = null;
SELECT @diff := TIMESTAMPDIFF(MINUTE, now(), end_at),
IF( @diff > 1440, @diff / 7, @diff) as minutesLeft
FROM table
```

Wrap the select in a sub-query if you just want one column returned.

Comment: All the returned rows are NULL

Comment: Sorry, should be := for in statement assignment. Corrected code in my reply - if for some reason it still does not work try setting @diff to 0.0 instead of NULL.